# Irreducibility of $x^2+x+4\in {\Bbb Z}_p[x]$ over ${\Bbb Z}_p$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

The following is an exercise in abstract algebra.

> Show that $x^2+x+4$ is irreducible over ${\Bbb Z}_{11}$.

One test all the elements in ${\Bbb Z}_{11}$ to show that $x^2+x+4$ has no zeros in ${\Bbb Z}_{11}$.

Here is my **question**:

> Can one know the irreducibility of $x^2+x+4\in{\Bbb Z}_p[x]$ for the general field ${\Bbb Z}_p$ where $p$ is prime?

Comment: In preparing for the answer by @N. S., I would emphasize that for $p \neq 2,$ this is legitimate: $$ f(x) \equiv \frac{1}{4} \; \left( (2x+1)^2 + 15  \right) \pmod p.  $$ This does not alter the question of existence of roots, so you are led fairly quickly to the Legendre symbol.

Comment: Similarly, for odd prime $p,$ if there is a solution to $$ w^2 \equiv -15 \pmod p$$ and $w$ is even, then another solution with an odd value is $$ (p-w)^2 \equiv -15 \pmod p. $$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. More exactly, this Polynomial is sometimes reducible and sometimes irreducible, and you can easily find a condition: $f(x)$ irreducible if and only if $p$ is of a certain form.

$$\Delta=1-16=-15 \,.$$

As Zev explained in his answer, in the case $p \neq 2$ you can find the quadratic formula by completing the square, while in the case $p=2$ it is trivial to check that our polynomial is reducible.

It follows that $x^2+x+4$ is irreducible in $\mathbb Z_{p}$ if and only if $\left(\frac{-15}{p}\right)=-1$ where this is the Legendre symbol.

Now, since

$$\left(\frac{-15}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{-1}{p}\right)\left(\frac{3}{p}\right)\left(\frac{5}{p}\right)$$
using quadratic residues you can easily find all primes for which this is $-1$.

**Added:** You need to leave out the cases $p=2, p=3, p=5$, it is easy to check what happens then. otherwise

$$\left(\frac{-1}{p}\right)=(-1)^\frac{p-1}{2}$$

$$\left(\frac{3}{p}\right)=1 \, \mbox{iff} \, p=\pm 1 \pmod{12}$$
$$\left(\frac{3}{p}\right)=-1 \, \mbox{iff} \, p=\pm 5 \pmod{12}$$

$$\left(\frac{5}{p}\right)=1 \, \mbox{iff} \, p=\pm 1 \pmod{5}$$
$$\left(\frac{5}{p}\right)=-1 \, \mbox{iff} \, p=\pm 2 \pmod{5}$$

So, now all you have to do is check the cases $p=2,3,5$ and then study $p \pmod{60}$.

Comment: You might want to explain why examining the discriminant is sufficent (the quadratic formula holds for any field of characteristic $\neq 2$).

Comment: @ZevChonoles, I put a short comment above

Comment: @ZevChonoles Ty, added.

Comment: @N.S. Thank you for your answer. I'm familiar with the Legendre symbol in number theory. Can I say that this is actually a way to find all the monic irreducible quadratic polynomials over ${\Bbb Z}_p$?

Comment: @Jack Yes. As Zev pointed you must discuss the case $p=2$ separately, and for $p\neq 2$ it is easy to prove that a quadratic is irreducible if and only if $\left(\frac{\Delta}{p}\right)=-1$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\rm\ \ f(x) = x^2 + x + 4\ $ is irreducible over $\rm\,\Bbb Z/p\,$ iff its discriminant $-15$ is not a square $\rm\,mod\ p.\:$ By quadratic reciprocity, $\rm\,(-15|p) = (-3|p)(5|p),\:$ and $\rm\,(-3|p) = 1\iff p\equiv 1\,\ (mod\ 6),\:$ and $\rm\,(5|p) = 1\iff p\equiv \pm1\,\ (mod\ 5).\:$ Thus $\rm\,(-3|p)(5|p) = -1\,$ if and only if

$$\begin{eqnarray} \rm\,p\equiv +1\,\ (mod\ 6),\ p\equiv \pm2\,\ (mod\ 5) &\iff& \rm\,p\equiv \ \,7,\ 13\,\ (mod\ 30)\\
\rm\,p\equiv -1\,\ (mod\ 6),\ p\equiv \pm1\,\ (mod\ 5) &\iff& \rm\,p\equiv 11,-1\,\ (mod\ 30)
\end{eqnarray}$$

Therefore $\rm\ x^2 + x + 4\:$ is irreducible $\rm\,mod\ p\ \iff\ p\equiv 7,11,13,29\,\ (mod\ 30).$